# Practical usage of keyword analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the scenario when you would need to use a mapping of [Keyword-Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) compared to marking it as `not_analyzed` with [Doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html)  turned on for the field.

1. From the elasticsearch documentation, it seems that if a field is not analyzed , then it is better to turn doc_Values on for this field.
2. The elasticsearch documentation also states specifically that [[sic]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) `Note, when using mapping definitions, it might make more sense to simply mark the field as not_analyzed`

I am a bit confused as to why the **Keyword** Analyzer will ever be used ?

Answer (score 1):

According to a core committer, [both are equivalent](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/Z_GaWBNpnp4).

That wouldn't be the case of the [`keyword` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html), though, which can be combined with other filters (lowercase, etc) and thus participate in many different ways of tokenizing your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact usecase for **keyword** analyzer, analyzers allow you to add character filters in addition to common filters and that's where they are used.

I had a field containing numeric values including whitespaces. Numbers may be persian , for ex `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` or English, so i needed a char filter to normalize them to english ones with a char filter without any other tokenizing process, when I marked the field **not_analyzed** I was unable to use my char filter.